# Steam crashes on launch at OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, dependencies, steam

I want to run Steam under OpenSUSE. I'm using [this manual](https://en.opensuse.org/Steam) for installation. But when I run it I get the following messages on the console:

```
$ STEAM_RUNTIME=1 steam                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Running Steam on opensuse 42.1 64-bit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled by the user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element                                                                                                                                                                           
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element                                                                                                                                                                           
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number                                                                                                                                                                      
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 62: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 70: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 78: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 86: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 94: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 102: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 110: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 118: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 126: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 134: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 142: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 150: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 158: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 166: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 174: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 182: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 190: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 198: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 206: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 214: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 222: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 230: bad alias                                                                                                                                                                                            
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 238: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 248: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 256: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 264: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 272: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 280: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 288: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 296: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 304: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 312: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 320: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 328: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 336: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 344: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 352: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 360: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 368: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 376: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 387: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 395: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 403: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 411: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 421: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 429: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 437: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 445: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 459: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 467: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 476: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 485: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 494: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 504: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 513: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 523: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 533: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 545: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 553: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 564: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 575: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 583: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 591: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 599: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 607: bad alias
[0702/151425:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0702/151425:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160614232302)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465946582)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160614232302)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465948400)
[0702/151425:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 62: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 70: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 78: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 86: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 94: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 102: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 110: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 118: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 126: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 134: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 142: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 150: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 158: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 166: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 174: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 182: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 190: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 198: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 206: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 214: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 222: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 230: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 238: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 248: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 256: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 264: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 272: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 280: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 288: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 296: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 304: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 312: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 320: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 328: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 336: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 344: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 352: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 360: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 368: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 376: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 387: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 395: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 403: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 411: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 421: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 429: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 437: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 445: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 459: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 467: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 476: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 485: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 494: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 504: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 513: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 523: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 533: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 545: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 553: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 564: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 575: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 583: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 591: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 599: bad alias
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 607: bad alias
crash_20160702151423_1.dmp[32009]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20160702151423_1.dmp
/home/noir/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 753: 31952 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
[0702/151426:WARNING:channel.cc(359)] RawChannel write error
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
crash_20160702151423_1.dmp[32009]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20160702151423_1.dmp[32009]: response: CrashID=bp-a7b77594-567b-41a8-b6a9-1be2c2160702
crash_20160702151423_1.dmp[32009]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20160702151423_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-a7b77594-567b-41a8-b6a9-1be2c2160702''
```

This Fontconfig error look suspicious but my research shows that this is no show stopper. I also tried to disable the steam runtime but after installing all 32 bit dependencies this also fails with the following console output:

```
$ STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam
Running Steam on opensuse 42.1 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is disabled by the user
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
[0702/160921:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0702/160921:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160614232302)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160614232302)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465946582)
[0702/160921:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
crash_20160702160919_1.dmp[23287]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20160702160919_1.dmp
/home/davy/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 753: 23233 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
crash_20160702160919_1.dmp[23287]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20160702160919_1.dmp[23287]: response: CrashID=bp-4b3423d5-5161-48de-af3f-e33e82160702
crash_20160702160919_1.dmp[23287]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20160702160919_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-4b3423d5-5161-48de-af3f-e33e82160702''
```

Here's some information about my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux suse-noir-desktop 4.1.20-11-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 18 14:42:07 UTC 2016 (0a392b2) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Jul  2 15:26:40 2016       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 361.42     Driver Version: 361.42         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTS 450     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 54%   42C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    588MiB /  1020MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have no idea what else I can try now. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe try using an open source video driver, rather than the nvidia one? See [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2310243/steam-fails-run-ubuntu.html) for more info.

Comment: I removed the driver and re-installed steam but it's still crashing with and without steam runtime.